# Локальные координаты на самом деле глобальные Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Используя стрелки на изображении я передвигаю кубик в локальных координатах
[image: Стрелки]

Но когда я пытаюсь использовать эти локальные координаты, кубик перемещается не по оси локальных, а по оси глобальных координат

[image: Локальные координаты]

Вот так он выглядел раньше

[image: Так было раньше]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90002/discussion-on-question-by--------).

Answer (score 1):

Я выбрал debug случайно давно видимо и не изменил вид. Поэтому была эта проблема